# 99 chevy suburban motor kicks back

Tags: engine, chevrolet, suburban

What would cause a fuel injected motor to kick back while cranking it? I have a 1999 chevy suburban 4wd 5.7 ltr.  I know it needs an intake manifold gasket, but would that cause it to kick back and ruin my starters?

Comment: [![crank position sensor if deffective will pull the timing 50 degrees and trow a silent code p1338
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNOZz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNOZz.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your truck needs an intake manifold gasket (actually you'll change both sides if you do), get this done and see if it solves your problems. Fix the things which you know need fixed. This may or may not solve your backfire issue, but at least you can go from there.

Timing is the most conventional thought here, though. I believe the 99 still had the GENI SBC which utilized the HEI distributor (2000 is the first year for the LM7, right?). Double check to ensure your spark plug wires are in the proper order (especially if you just did a tune-up). Also, as long as the distributor wasn't removed, the normal position of the HEI should be 90deg (perpendicular) to the longitudinal axis of the engine (axis is front to back, cap of distributor should be left to right), with the wire harness coming off of the driver's side of the cap.

Comment: Yeah I had a shop look at it today, he scanned for codes and said the timing and distributer were right where they needed to be but it had a misfire. I originally took it in to see why the starter was screaching after replacing to starters. he said the starter was fine but the motor would kick back upon starting and making the starter screach. he didnt know it would kick back though, and couldnt give me a price on changing the intake gasket.

Comment: 1999 Suburban would have been the L31 Vortec 5.7. 1999 Silverado/Sierra 1500 had the new Gen III engine though.